# Batch extract numbers between quotes, multiply and write back

Tags: xml, batch-file

I have a text file and I extract the needed portion with the following batch code:

```
@echo off > newfile & setLocal enableDELAYedeXpansioN

set H=
set T=
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "<face>" ^< C:\XML\INTERM\image-0000001.txt') do (
set H=%%a
)
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "</face>" ^< C:\XML\INTERM\image-0000001.txt') do (
set T=%%a
)
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v "" ^< C:\XML\INTERM\image-0000001.txt') do (
if %%a gtr !H! if %%a lss !T! echo.%%b
)>> c:\XML\ADD\image-0000001.txt
goto :eof
```

My result text file is:

```
<attribute name="personName">Test</attribute>
<attribute name="face-type">human</attribute>
<geometry>
<LinearRing ptCount="36">
<Point x="968.13" y="762.91"/>
<Point x="940.54" y="764.38"/>
<Point x="921.17" y="755.09"/>
<Point x="905.96" y="742.91"/>
<Point x="909" y="705.92"/>
<Point x="918.23" y="660.54"/>
<Point x="926.39" y="629"/>
<Point x="875.92" y="638.23"/>
<Point x="869.77" y="664.38"/>
<Point x="862.08" y="689.77"/>
<Point x="847.46" y="701.31"/>
<Point x="829.77" y="702.85"/>
<Point x="840.3" y="655.52"/>
<Point x="849" y="607.7"/>
<Point x="854.22" y="560.3"/>
<Point x="886.39" y="520.74"/>
<Point x="922.48" y="501.17"/>
<Point x="966.83" y="476.39"/>
<Point x="1001.61" y="445.96"/>
<Point x="1027.26" y="412.04"/>
<Point x="1038.23" y="393.62"/>
<Point x="1051.31" y="417.46"/>
<Point x="1062.08" y="445.92"/>
<Point x="1067.46" y="472.08"/>
<Point x="1075.15" y="505.15"/>
<Point x="1078.23" y="536.69"/>
<Point x="1073.62" y="562.85"/>
<Point x="1062.85" y="592.85"/>
<Point x="1039.87" y="622.91"/>
<Point x="1017.7" y="640.3"/>
<Point x="1003.35" y="658.13"/>
<Point x="1005.09" y="675.09"/>
<Point x="1003.35" y="691.61"/>
<Point x="999.87" y="712.04"/>
<Point x="992.91" y="728.13"/>
<Point x="982.04" y="742.48"/>
</LinearRing>
</geometry>
<eye>
<geometry>
<Rectangle x="995.9565217391305" y="661.6086956521739" width="5.217391304347757" height="12.608695652173992"/>
</geometry>
<eye-bounds>
<attribute name="occlusion">hidden</attribute>
<attribute name="open-closed-state">half-open</attribute>
<geometry>
<Rectangle x="973.3478260869565" y="659.4347826086956" width="29.565217391304373" height="21.739130434782624"/>
</geometry>
</eye-bounds>
</eye>
```

I need to extract every number between double quotes from `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`, (not for `LinearRing ptCount="36"`), multiply each with `2` and write back, one by one. I have to mention the number of `Point` tags (wich is 36 in this case) may vary. My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: I almost thought this was a good question... Code, output and then there was the question for free code... And the answer on that question is no... SO is not a free code writing service and if you are new to batch, the best you can do is use your task to train it. Come back if you have a direct question that you could not find an answer for on google/SO! In addition to that: Batch is not good in handling float numbers

Comment: batch can handle integers only. You'll have to use either a lot of code to make it handle floating point numbers or use another language (which will be almost certainly be also better suited than batch to handle xml-formatted files)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a "simple" and fast solution that relies on [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). It completely replaces your entire script.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "input=C:\XML\INTERM\image-0000001.txt"
set "output=c:\XML\ADD\image-0000001.txt"

jrepl "<face>([\s\S]*)</face>" $1 /m /jmatch /f "%input%" | ^
jrepl "((?:x|y|width|height)=\q)([^\q]*)(\q)" "$txt=$1+(Number($2)*2)+$3" /x /jq /o "%output%"
```

But really you should be using a tool that is designed to process XML files.

Comment: Hi, I have tested and the results is what I expected! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution that accomplishes what you want but in a quite slow manner.

The following restrictions apply:

- the XML file is treated as a "normal" text file;
- the file must be ANSI-encoded;
- the file must be a Windows text file (the end-of-line marker is carriage-return plus line-feed);
- empty lines get lost;
- lines must not be longer than about 8190 characters/bytes;
- the tags of interest (`Point`, `Rectangle`) must be in their own lines each;
- the tags of interest must be like `<Point/>`; something like `<Point>`, `</Point>` is not allowed;
- the tag names as well as the attribute names (`x`, `y`, `width`, `height`) must match exactly in terms of case;
- the attribute values must be (signed) floating-point numbers (no exponential format allowed);
- the floating-point numbers are rounded to have not more than eight fractional digits;
- the floating-point numbers must be less than 10<sup>8</sup> with respect to their absolute values;
- the integer factor to multiply the floating-point numbers with must not exceed a value of `21`;
- the resulting (multiplied) floating-point numbers are returned with exactly eight fractional digits;

So here is the code:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1"         & rem // (use file provided as first command line argument)
set "_FACTOR=%~2"       & rem // (use factor provided as second command line argument)
set "_TAG[1]=Point"     & rem // (name of XML tag containing numeric values)
set "_TAG[2]=Rectangle" & rem // (name of XML tag containing numeric values)
rem "_TAG[...]=..."
set "_ATT[1]=x"         & rem // (name of XML attribute holding a numeric value)
set "_ATT[2]=y"         & rem // (name of XML attribute holding a numeric value)
set "_ATT[3]=width"     & rem // (name of XML attribute holding a numeric value)
set "_ATT[4]=height"    & rem // (name of XML attribute holding a numeric value)
rem "_ATT[...]=..."

rem // Main routine: check tag names and tag format:
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%K in ("%_FILE%") do (
    set "LINE=%%K"
    set "FLAG="
    for /F "tokens=2,* delims=[]=" %%I in ('2^> nul set _TAG[') do (
        if not defined FLAG (
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            (cmd /V /C echo(^^!LINE^^!| > nul findstr /R ^
                /C:"^ *<%%J  *[^</>^&(|)][^</>^&(|)]*/> *$"
            ) && (
                for /F "tokens=1,* delims=< " %%L in ("!LINE!") do (
                    endlocal
                    set "COLL=%%L"
                    for /F "delims=/>" %%N in ("%%M") do (
                        call :ATTRIBUTE COLL "%%N" && set "FLAG=#"
                    )
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                )
            )
            endlocal
        )
    )
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if defined FLAG (
        echo(^<!COLL!/^>
    ) else (
        echo(!LINE!
    )
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B


:ATTRIBUTE  rtn_line_string  val_attribute
    rem // Sub-routine: check attribute names and format:
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    set "STR=%~2"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    :LOOP
    for /F "tokens=1,* delims= " %%A in ("!STR!") do (
        endlocal
        set "NEW=%%A"
        set "STR=%%B"
        set "FLG="
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%E in ('2^> nul set _ATT[') do (
            if not defined FLG (
                (cmd /V /C echo(^^!NEW^^!| > nul findstr /R ^
                    /C:"^%%F=\"[0-9\.+-][0-9\.]*\"$"
                ) && (
                    for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%C in ("!NEW!") do (
                        call :MULTIPLY PRO %%~C %_FACTOR% && (
                            for /F "delims=" %%D in ("!%~1! %%F="!PRO!"") do (
                                endlocal
                                set "%~1=%%D"
                                set "FLG=#"
                                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        if not defined FLG (
            endlocal
            endlocal
            set "%~1="
            exit /B 1
        )
    )
    if defined STR goto :LOOP
    for /F "delims=" %%D in (^""!%~1!"^") do (
        endlocal
        endlocal
        set "%~1=%%~D"
    )
    exit /B 0


:MULTIPLY  rtn_product  val_float_num  val_integer
    rem // Sub-routine: multiply of floating-point number by integer:
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    set "MUL=%~3" & if not defined MUL set /A "MUL=1"
    set /A "MUL+=0" & set "NEG="
    if %MUL% LSS 0 set /A "MUL=-MUL" & set "NEG=-"
    set "NUM=%~2" & if not defined NUM set "NUM=0"
    if "%NUM:~,1%"=="-" if defined NEG (set "NEG=") else (set "NEG=-")
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%X in ("%NUM%") do (
        set "INT=%%X" & set "FRA=%%Y"
    )
    for /F "tokens=* delims=+-0" %%Z in ("%INT%") do set "INT=%%Z"
    if not defined INT set "INT=0"
    if not "%INT:~,-8%"=="" goto :OVERFLOW
    set "FRA=1%FRA%00000000"
    if %FRA:~8,1% GEQ 5 (set /A "RND=1") else (set /A "RND=0")
    set /A "FRA=%FRA:~,9%%%100000000+RND"
    set /A "RSI=INT*MUL, RSF=FRA*MUL"
    if %RSF% LSS 0 goto :OVERFLOW
    if %RSF% NEQ 0 if %RSF% LSS %FRA% goto :OVERFLOW
    2> nul set /A "RSI+=%RSF:~,-8%" & set "RSF=00000000%RSF%"
    if %RSI% LSS 0 goto :OVERFLOW
    if %RSI% NEQ 0 if %RSI% LSS %INT% goto :OVERFLOW
    (
        endlocal
        set "%~1=%NEG%%RSI%.%RSF:~-8%"
    )
    exit /B 0
    :OVERFLOW
    endlocal
    set "%~1="
    exit /B 1
```

To use this script -- let us call it `xml-multiply.bat` --, provide the XML file (`result.xml`) as the first command line argument and the factor to multiply the attribute values with (`2` to double them) as the second one, like this:

```cmd
xml-multiply.bat "result.xml" 2
```

To have the output written into a file (`result_NEW.xml`), use this:

```cmd
xml-multiply.bat "result.xml" 2 > "result_NEW.xml"
```

To replace the original XML file, do this:

```cmd
xml-multiply.bat "result.xml" 2 > "result_NEW.xml"
move /Y "result_NEW.xml" "result.xml"
```

Comment: Hi, I have tested, but unfortunately it produced an empty xml file. Thank's anyway!

Comment: Are you sure all the limitations I listed are fulfilled?